# How to share information on client-side only?

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, gruntjs, leaflet

I currently have an AngularJS application that uses grunt to connect to port 3000. I want to be able to share data between all clients that are connected to that port. I know socket-io is a popular method for doing so but I can't seem to get it to work. Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: *"can't seem to get it to work"* ... figure out why. websockets are ideal for what you need

Comment: It is considered off-topic to ask us to recommend resources, as it attracts opinionated answers and spam.